# Add buttons for custom styles to CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

CKEditor lets you add custom styles to the styles combo box by editing the file styles.js (see  [What is a good javascript HTML editor for adding custom HTML elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808426/what-is-a-good-javascript-html-editor-for-adding-custom-html-elements) for details)

I would like to add unique buttons to the toolbar to apply my custom styles, rather than the user having to select them from the styles combo.

How do you add custom buttons to the CKEditor toolbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go ahead with the following code:

```
// Your custom style.
var myStyle = new CKEDITOR.style( {
    element: 'span',
    attributes: {
        'data-foo': 'bar',
        'class': 'myClass'
    },
    styles: {
        color: 'red'
    }
} );

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        // Register command and button along with other plugins.
        pluginsLoaded: function() {
            var editor = this;

            // Registers a command that applies the style.
            // Note: it automatically adds Advanced Content Filter rules.
            this.addCommand( 'myStyle', new CKEDITOR.styleCommand( myStyle ) );

            // Add toolbar button for this command.
            this.ui.addButton && this.ui.addButton( 'myStyleButton', {
                label: 'My style',
                command: 'myStyle',
                toolbar: 'insert,10'
                // You may want to set some icon here.
                // icon: 'someIcon'
            } );
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you confirm which file(s) this code should go into? Should it be in styles.js or do I need to edit more than one file?

Comment: It depends on how you define your config. You should put this `pluginsLoaded` listener there and make sure that `myStyle` is within a scope.

Comment: I have put in a separate script that runs after the page has loaded, and it seems to work just fine! One small thing: how do you define a new toolbar? The example above adds the new buttons to the 'insert' toolbar. I would like to put all my custom buttons on their own separate toolbar. Thank you!