# How to disable / hide and alter some elements in CK-editor image pop-up

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I have a VB forum that uses the CK editor which is amazing, but there are many features on the editor that simply confuse my members, most specifically in the image upload/attachment popup.  I would like to simplify the popup by hiding some of the elements and changing some text descriptions.  I asked for help on the VBulletin website, but because this is a plugin for their software, they don't really have much advice to help me accomplish what I would like to do.  So, I thought I would go to the source.

This is what the pop-up looks like currently:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bLFU.jpg)

I made a mock-up image of what I would like the image pop-up to contain.  I would want my forum logo to display instead of the VB logo or just have no logo there at all if it is too complicated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqF3I.jpg)

I looked at the JavaScript for the popup and it was way too complex for a novice like me to begin to edit without detailed instruction. So, I thought maybe I could hide the unwanted elements using CSS.  It looked good but still has a big footprint. Here is what I came up with:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knaPN.jpg)

The way I accomplished this was with the following CSS code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mKiz.jpg)

This CSS edit works great on the desktop site, but the fields return if I visit the site on my mobile device. I put my browser into developer mode and chose the different phone and tablet settings and the hidden elements re-appear. I inspected the containers that I hid and the numbers are the same. For some reason, they show even though they are hidden by CSS. When I go back to the desktop browser, the elements are correctly hidden again. I thought maybe it was a browser cache issue at first, but it happens in both Firefox and Chrome as well as the internet browser on my phone and chrome there as well.  I was able to get it to work like I described using the Firefox browser, but when I switch to Chrome browser, all the hidden elements reappear. :(

Anyway, I'm out of ideas on how to solve this issue on my own.  So, my question(s):

1. Is there a way that I can edit the CK editor plugin to accomplish the simple pop-up I want for my site?
2. If so, can someone supply the correct code and the JavaScript file name I need to edit?

I would be most appreciative for any guidance.  Thank you, sincerely.

Kether

Comment: Hello. Have you tried taking a look at these other SO questions that cover similar customization? Also, what version of CKEditor are you working with?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102797/adding-custom-styles-to-ckeditor
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054351/add-buttons-for-custom-styles-to-ckeditor